# Web Scraping via Python Requests returning gibberish

Tags: python

I'm very, very new to Python and thought I would try to experiment with some practical applications.

I'm trying to put together a basic web price scraper using the requests library. I picked this webpage :https://www.usstoragecenters.com/storage-units/fl/north-miami-beach/15555-w-dixie-hwy

This is the basic structure that I am using:

```
import requests

page = requests.get("my url from above")
page

page.content
```

But for some reason the html print via .content or .text looks very wrong. Instead of seeing the html structure I get what looks like a ton of carriage returns. There is definitely missing data.

I tried parsing using beautiful soup (html-parser,html5lib, etc.) which cut out even more of the data.

Is this just coded in a way that blocks scraping or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you just type that in the terminal, it will print the `repr`, which will have `\n` and such. What if you print it instead?

Answer (score 1):

**Issue :**

Problem you are facing is that there are embedded javascript in htmls due to which you will see data missing in html page. so here([requests_html]) is a very nice library designed to request htmls by kennethreitz

**Sample Code :**

```
from requests_html import *
sessions = Session()
r = sessions.get('https://www.usstoragecenters.com/storage-units/fl/north-miami-beach/15555-w-dixie-hwy')
for lines in r.iter_lines() :
    print(lines)
```

**Sample output**

Due to the comment size limtation i cannot post the full html , here is the piece of HTML printed with above print

```
b'<!doctype html>'
b'<html>'
b'<head>'
b'<meta charset="utf-8">'
b'<title>Self Storage Units at 15555 West Dixie Highway, North Miami Beach, FL 33162 | US Storage Centers</title>'
b'<base href="/">'
b'<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />'
b'<meta name="description" content="Brand New Facility Grand Opening! Special 50% Off Self Storage. Friendly Service. Reserve Online for Free. No Credit Card Required." />'
b'<meta property="og:type" content="website" />'
b'<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />'
b'<meta property="og:site_name" content="US Storage Centers" />'
b'<meta property="og:title" content="Self Storage North Miami Beach" />'
b'<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.usstoragecenters.com/storage-units/fl/north-miami-beach/15555-w-dixie-hwy" />'
b'<meta property="og:description" content="Brand New Facility Grand Opening! Special 50% Off Self Storage. Friendly Service. Reserve Online for Free. No Credit Card Required." />'
b'<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.usstoragecenters.com/www/images/ussc_facility_photos/168/2017-06-15_00-37-08_Self%20Storage%20Building%20Exterior%20Front%20-%20North%20Miami%20Beach%20West%20Dixie%20IMG_5237%208.jpg" />'
b'<script type="application/ld+json">'
b'            {'
b'                    "@context": "http://schema.org",'
b'                    "@type": "WebPage"'
b'                    ,"breadcrumb": {'
b'                            "@context": "http://schema.org",'
b'                            "@type": "BreadcrumbList",'
b'                            "itemListElement": [{'
b'                    "@type": "ListItem",'
b'                    "name": "US Storage Centers",'
b'                    "url": "https://www.usstoragecenters.com/",'
b'                    "position": 0'
b'                }, {'
b'                    "@type": "ListItem",'
b'                    "name": "Storage Units",'
b'                    "url": "https://www.usstoragecenters.com/storage-units",'
b'                    "position": 1'
b'                }, {'
b'                    "@type": "ListItem",'
b'                    "name": "FL",'
b'                    "url": "https://www.usstoragecenters.com/storage-units/fl",'
b'                    "position": 2'
b'                }, {'

 **...... truncated  .....**
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me `requests_html`, it's very simple to use. If you want to fix your code, change `Session` to `HTMLSession` and call `r.html.render()` to actually render the page. After that, `r.html.find('some#css.selector')` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Call `print(page.content)`

It will encode the returns, etc. as they should appear (newlines, tabs, etc.)

A test:

```
s = """
     Hey
    \r\r\r\r\r Look
    \t\t\t\t\t\t Here"""
print(s)
```

Output:

```
 Hey





 Look
                             Here
```

Answer (score 0):

What you see with a browser's developer tools doesn't correspond to what's in the HTML returned by the webserver. Look at the source code in your web browser and you will see that *all* of the webpage's content is generated with JavaScript from the JSON contained in the `<script>` tags.

This makes your life a lot easier, since you don't have to worry much about parsing the HTML and only extract the data from the JSON:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

...

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)

# Find the `script` tag with no `src` and 'window.jsonData' in its text
script = soup.find('script', src=None, text=lambda text: 'window.jsonData' in text).get_text()


# The JSON is part of script, so just remove the extra stuff
script = script.strip().replace('window.jsonData = ', '').rstrip(';')

# Now parse it
data = json.loads(script)
```

Comment: I tried this but got an error at Soup = BeautifulSou(page.text) for not identifying a parser and then another error at the find script piece for not defining "none"?

Comment: @sccrbrg: you only get a warning at the `soup =` line because no parser is specified. Read the warning text and it tells you how to resolve it. As for the other error, I don't have any problems running this code. You'll have to post the full traceback of the error message.

Comment: So I did get that to work by running the whole code at once, I was trying to run it line by line and ran into an issue for some reason. I was planning on using the html tags to identify the items that i wanted to isolate but given the format I don't think that will work here. Any suggestions? I appreciate the help.

Comment: @sccrbrg: Search through the JSON for the data you want, it's structured. For example, look at the dictionaries in `data['data']['content'][0]['context']['units']`.